# Fetch behavior when appending element?

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch-api

Why does the `appendChild` properly work? The console.log shows an empty tr element which I assume is because of the fetch(in the api_search function) being asynchronous, but somehow the appendChild manages to fill in my table with the fetched data, so how is the row different in there as opposed to the console.log?

```js
let row = document.createElement("tr");
if (ref.record) {
  api_search(ref.record.$ref, {
      fields: ['titles', 'authors', 'citation_count']
    })
    .then(data => {
      var title = data.titles[0].title
      var url = api_to_url(ref.record.$ref)
      var authors = data.authors
      var citations = data.citation_count

      row.innerHTML = inspire_paper_info(title, authors, url, citations)
    })
  console.log(row)
  inspireTable.appendChild(row)
}
```

Comment: You are logging the row while it's empty, and you are appending it while it's empty, but then later on your data arrives and in your `then` you are changing the contents of the (already-appended) row by writing `row.innerHTML = ...`. You could also do `row.innerHTML = '<td colspan="4">Loading...</td>'` (with `4` being the number of columns, I just guessed) before the `appendChild` and you'll get a row saying `Loading...` and later getting its contents replaced by the actual data once it arrived.

Comment: Ah I see, that also explains some of my other issues, thank you very much.